# Rails 2 route helpers in plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, helper

I'm trying to write a plugin, and among the tasks I want to perform I want to be able to call route helper methods from within the plugin. For instance, if I have `map.resources :user`, I want to be able to call `user_path(:id => 1)` from my plugin. I keep getting undefined method user_path error.

In rails 3, you can do this using `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`, but I don't seem to be able to find an alternative for rails 2. Including [ActionController::UrlWriter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/) does not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using rails 2.3.4 and i can use my regular path helpers in the controllers and views of my plugins, at least within the ones i tested.

I can't use them in the lib files for the plugins, but that's because the helpers aren't available outside the controllers (the views are dealt with inside the controllers so they can use them too).  The lib files (the meat of the plugins) tends to be modules and classes which get loaded into the model environment.

Can you provide more details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to fix the [gretel breadcrumbs plugin](https://github.com/lassebunk/gretel/) to be rails 2 compatible. The problem like you stated is in the lib files, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You were right on the money, the problem was that I was trying to use them in the lib files, instead of controller/view/helper. I didn't catch it quickly cause I was using lambdas and didn't quite understand closures (the lambda was called in the helper, but it had the scope of the lib file). Thanx for you answer.

Comment: Can you share the solution? Because i can't figure it out from these comments, how did you use the plugin with rails 2.3

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
app.user_path(1)
```

Comment: this works from the console, but in my plugin, it says: undefined local variable or method "app"